# Setting a default CookieManager on WebLogic has no effect

Tags: java, spring, soap, weblogic, spring-ws

I am using Spring's **WebServiceGatewaySupport** to connect to a vendor's SOAP Web Service. One of the requirements of this service is that the client must maintain the session cookie sent by the server.

I was able to determine that **WebServiceGatewaySupport** internally uses the **HttpURLConnection** class to make requests. Simply calling

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

before the party gets started adds a default cookie manager and everything works delightfully peachy keen on my local Tomcat instance (I even noted a small rainbow appear next to my machine).

But, when I deploy to WebLogic 10.3.6.0, everything goes all Miley Cyrus. It doesn't twerk like it used to and my cookies are being tossed.

I was able to prove WebLogic is the culprit by overriding the get and put methods of the CookieManager.  Plenty of action on these in Tomcat. Not a murmur from WebLogic.

```
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, List<String>> get(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap) throws IOException {
            Map<String, List<String>> map =  super.get(uri, stringListMap);
            LOGGER.info("Cop that: " + uri + " " + map);
            return map;
        }

        @Override
        public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> stringListMap) throws IOException {
            LOGGER.info("Hello sailor: " + uri + " " + stringListMap);
            super.put(uri, stringListMap);
        }
    });
    ((CookieManager)CookieHandler.getDefault()).setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
```

I can only assume there is some kind of "advanced security shenanigans" intended for incoming servlet requests but is being applied to outgoing connections also. I cant find any weblogic deployment descriptor options that would be of any use.

Bugger.

I can probably get it working with Axis but id rather stab myself in the face with a pen.

I'm going home.

---

Update: Ok, I haven't solved the root cause, but this how I got it working. I was thinking if I could get access to the actual HttpURLConnection object I can do manual cookie management on it.  I was able to look at the Spring WS source and set a new MessageSender which works mostly the same.

```
public class MyClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    public MyClient(WebServiceMessageFactory messageFactory) {
        super(messageFactory);

        super.getWebServiceTemplate().setMessageSender(new WebServiceMessageSender() {
            @Override
            public WebServiceConnection createConnection(URI uri) throws IOException {
                URL url = uri.toURL();
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                if (!(connection instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
                    throw new HttpTransportException("URI [" + uri + "] is not an HTTP URL");
                }
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                prepareConnection(httpURLConnection);

                HttpURLConnectionProxy httpURLConnectionProxy = new HttpURLConnectionProxy(url);
                httpURLConnectionProxy.setHttpURLConnection(httpURLConnection);
                httpURLConnectionProxy.setCookieManager(cookieManager);
                return new MyHttpUrlConnection(httpURLConnectionProxy);
            }

            protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
                connection.setRequestMethod(HttpTransportConstants.METHOD_POST);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                // ORRRRR YEAAHHHHHHH!
                cookieManager.setCookies(connection);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(URI uri) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Another complication was that I needed to set and get cookie data before and after connect() was called. So I made a HttpURLConnectionProxy class which proxies all the method calls to the one generated by url.openConnection() but does cookie stuff after connect();

```
public void connect() throws IOException {
    httpURLConnection.connect();
    // WOOPWOOPWOOPWOOP!
    cookieManager.storeCookies(httpURLConnection);
}
```

But it TWERKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are twisting the CookieManager API intended use. Please reference the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/cookiemanager.html) and the [CookieManager documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html). 
Your vendor's requirement is to maintain the session cookie sent by the server. For this requirement to be achieved you want TWO steps:

1. Within the Spring container, wire a Spring bean which holds the method invocation CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
2. Within the client code initialize a URI instance which will identify the cookies in the CookieStore

#### Step 1

Assuming you are using Spring 3.1 or later, please find below your Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc   // this annotation imports the class  WebMvcConfigurationSupport which bootstraps web mvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.orgname"  })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/view/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

/**
 * This method invocation bean stands for the method call:
 * CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
 * which should be done at the beginning of an HTTP session to bootstrap
 * the Java 6 Http state management mechanism for the application as a whole. 
 * (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/cookiehandler.html)
 * 
 */
@Bean(name="cookieHandlerSetDefaultBean") 
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() { 
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(CookieHandler.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("setDefault");
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(new Object[]{cookieManager}); 
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean; 
}
}
```

#### Step 2

Given that your client class is a Spring Service or Component. Please find below its code.

```
/**
 * This service aggregates the default CookieManager as explained in the API 
 * (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html). 
 * A system-wide CookieManager that is used by the HTTP protocol handler 
 * can be retrieved by calling CookieHandler.getDefault(). 
 * A CookieManager is initialized with aآ CookieStoreآ which manages storage
 * A CookieStore supports add(cookie) and getCookie() methods
 * A CookieStore is responsible of removing Cookie instances which have expired.
 *
 */
@Service(value="serviceConfigBean")
@DependsOn(value="cookieHandlerSetDefault")    //This is the bean initialized in the Configuration class. It is needed to be initialized before the container initializes the Service 
public class ClientCookiesStore {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientCookiesStore.class);

    protected CookieStore inmemoryCookieStore;

    protected URI clientURI;

/**
 * The @PostConstruct (lifecycle callback method) indicates this method should be invoked after all 
 * dependency injection is complete. Thus helps in initializing any resources needed by the 
 * service.
 * 
 * In this particular initializing method:
 * (as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html
 *  and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/cookiemanager.html)
 * The CookieHandler default is installed in the application via 
 * a method invoking factory bean, namely "cookieHandlerSetDefault" which 
 * exists in the java configuration file WebConfig.java

 * (1) A cookieManager property needs 2 steps setup as indicated in the code
 * (2) The internal in-memory implementation of the CookieStore interface is initialized 
 *      through the cookieManager defaults. It is assigned to the inmemoryCookieStore property.  
 * (3) Since a CookieStore aggregates many groups of cookies, each group is identified 
 *     by a URI instance. ClientCookiesStore is associated with the Client URI as indicated in 
 *     the code.  
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
@PostConstruct
protected void initializeBean() throws Exception {
    //      (1) Step#1 Initialize a CookieManager with the current Http session default 
    //                  which was already set in the configuration class
    CookieManager cookieManager = (CookieManager)CookieHandler.getDefault();    
    //          Step#2 Then set up the CookiePolicy.
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    //      (2) Assign a CookieStore instance to the in-memory cookie store implemented by the API
    inmemoryCookieStore =  cookieManager.getCookieStore();
    //      (3) Initialize URI instance which will identify the Client cookies in the CookieStore 

    try {
        clientURI = new URI("http://vendor.webservices.com/endpoint");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new Exception("URISyntaxException created while creating a URI instance for url= "+clientUrl);
    }
}
```

}

All what is left are the 2 methods to add a new cookie and to retrieve the cookie from the inmemory store. Both methods belong to the above ClientCookiesStore Class.

```
public List<HttpCookie> getCookiesList() throws Exception {
    List<HttpCookie> httpCookiesList = inmemoryCookieStore.get(clientURI);
    return httpCookiesList;
}

public void addCookie(HttpCookie newCookie) {
        inmemoryCookieStore.add(clientURI, newCookie);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I will try this. (Just a note: The CookieManager in my "hack" is not the system cookie manager. It is a custom implementation.)

Comment: Thanks sam. I haven't had time to try your answer (i got my hack working and my boss has me working on other things). Im interested why that simple "CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());" call works fine with Tomcat but Weblogic would require the extra wiring. If i don't get a chance to test it soon, I'll accept it as solved.